# Limite en bucle for para leer un rss - JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy creando algo asi como un banner para customizar un fondo de pantalla con un fichero html

Encontré un script en javascript que te lee los feeds RSS y te los colocar en un fichero html.

Luego con el CSS he podido dejarlo a mi gusto y queda bien.

Me encuentro, que principalmente no se como limitar la cantidad de entradas lee el script de la url (RSS).

Os paso un poco el codigo que tengo:

javascript

```
 let url = 'https://catalunyadiari.com/rss/cat/actualitat';
  const textarea = document.querySelector('#feed-textarea > ul');
 
    feednami.load(url)
    .then(feed => {
      textarea.value = ''
      for(let entry of feed.entries){
          //create a list element
          let li = document.createElement('li');
          //add HTML content to list items
          li.innerHTML = `${entry.title}`;
          //append HTML content to list 
          textarea.appendChild(li);
      }
    });
```

html

```
<section class="news-wrapped">
    <h3 id="date"></h3>
    <div class="news">
        <div id="feed-textarea">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.news div:nth-child(-n+10){
    animation: slide 12s infinite;

}

@keyframes slide{


    0%{ margin-top: -240px;}
    5%{ margin-top: -160px;}
    35%{margin-top: -160px;}
    40%{margin-top: -80px;}

}
```

este script me genera como 20 lineas "li", por lo que al hacer las transiciones entre 'li' esto me fastidia todas las animaciones.

Entonces tengo dos opciones:

- Limito la cantidad de elementos que genera el script.
- Efecto en css que sea uniforme para que las animaciones vayan bien.

Como podría solucionar esto, veo que casi lo tengo pero no acabo de rematarlo.

MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO!!

Comment: Hola ¿podrías explicar un poco más a que te refieres con "fastidia las animaciones"?

Comment: Ups!! Claro!

Hace una lista, esta puesto dentro del <div> "news" entonces va haciendo un efecto de cambiar este cada elemento de la lista.
Algo así como esta imagen:

http://www.imagebam.com/image/7f811a1348618049

Pero pasa que como tengo puesto el limite en 12s, se lee bien los 5 primeros elementos y los siguientes van muy rapido.
y vuelve a comenzar el bucle de efecto CSS.